# html & css - positioning divs at exact coordinates

Tags: html, css

i'm trying to recreate this image in pure html and css, or add a little javascript if nessascary:

[image: LCARS image]

and here's what i have so far:

[image: jeffs beautiful unfinished handywork]

i'm trying to move that small orange box near the center up to match the blue line, but she won't budge

```
.middletop {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #fe9800;
    width: 26px;
    height: 16px;
    left: 471px;
}
```

and here's the entire code:

layout.html

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>LCARS</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="static/style.css"/>
</head>

<body>
<div class="topleft">
</div>

<div class="topleft2">
</div>  

<div class="middletop">
</div>

<div class="bottomleft">
</div>

<div class="bottomleft2">
</div>

<div class="bottomleft3">
</div>

<div class="bottomleft4">
</div>

<div class="content">
</div>

<div class="content2">
</div>

</body>

<footer>


</footer>
</html>
```

**style.css**

```
body {
    background-color: black;
}

.topleft {
    background-color: #c498c4;
    width: 126px;
    height: 90px;
}

.topleft2 {
    margin-top: 5px;
    background-color: #9b98fe;
    width: 463px;
    height: 112px;
    border-radius: 0 0 0 70px;
}

.bottomleft {
    margin-top: 7px;
    background-color: #cc6061;
    width: 463px;
    height: 91px;
    border-radius: 70px 0 0 0;
}

.bottomleft2 {
    margin-top: 5px;
    background-color: #cc6061;
    width: 126px;
    height: 137px;
}

.bottomleft3 {
    margin-top: 5px;
    background-color: #fe9800;
    width: 126px;
    height: 38px;
}

.bottomleft4 {
    margin-top: 5px;
    background-color: #ffa873;
    width: 126px;
    height: 180px;
}

.middletop {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #fe9800;
    width: 26px;
    height: 16px;
    left: 471px;
}

.content {
    background-color: /*#6D6A6A*/black;
    position: absolute;
    left: 127px;
    top: 239px;
    border-radius: 35px;
    width: 900px;
    height: 700px;
}

.content2 {
    background-color: black;
    position: absolute;
    left: 127px;
    top: -2;
    border-radius: 0 0 0 35px;
    width: 900px;
    height: 200px;
}
```

Comment: You don't seem to have a `top` or `bottom` position on the `middletop` element.  Is that the orange box? If so, give it a top...

Comment: i did...... and it just disappears........

Comment: Where is it being positioned relative to? Do you use a tool like Firebug for Firefox? If so, you can fiddle with the position in order to "find" it.  Chances are it's disappearing behind something...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I advise having a look into using absolute positioning extensively, if you're already doing it and you're happy with it, you just have to set `top` and you should be good to go:

```css
.middletop {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #fe9800;
    width: 26px;
    height: 16px;
    left: 476px;
    top:199px /* <-- this is what I added */
}
```

**[Here is a demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/7Wz6C/)**

Comment: thanks, i tried using top and bottom before i posted this and it just disappeared and i couldn't find it.

Answer (score 0):

Use the css `top:100px;`. And to see it use: `z-index:100;`

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
 position: absolute;
 top: /*the amount of px from the top to your wanted location*/;
 left: /*the amount of px from the left to your wanted location*/;
 z-index:1000; /*<= this is to be above all other elements*/
```